# angular $sce trustAsResourceUrl from node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, videogular

im trying to make a streaming service where i stream the content of a file (in this case a video) into a video element.

for this purpose i have downloaded and installed `videogular` and is now trying to set it up however im sure how to do it.

According to the documentation on videogular to load a video you would need a syntax like this:

```
sources: [
    {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(myMp4Resource), type: "video/mp4"}
]
```

Which is fine for when you want to load the content in without streaming.

But say for instance you have a node server running at port 8105 and the file you wish to collect had an id of 1 then the result might look something like this:

```
sources: [
    {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:8105/loadvideo/1'), type: "video/mp4"}
]
```

However in my attempt to do so it would just tell me that the resource is not an actual resource.

My question is how do you stream to a video content (preferably with videogular) and does anyone know of examples where people have made this possible?

**Server side code**

Okay so my initial idea (and i know this is a change for the code above) was to create a `route` that took at path:

```
    router.route('/retrieveFile')
    .post(function (request, response) {
        var path = '../' + request.body.data;
        var file = fs.createReadStream(path);
        file.pipe(response);
    });
```

And then piped the output of the file.

Then use this to stream the file

Comment: And pointing your browser to http://localhost:8105/loadvideo/1 actually downloads the video?

Comment: @laggingreflex well as an example it should collect the video and stream it but im not quite sure where to go from here or if i am doing it correctly i cant seem to find any examples so i am kinda throwing things into the dark

Comment: Can you create a simple fiddle, so that we can work on that and see what is not coming. Coz, it works well this way.

Comment: ive added some server side code please do note that i am not exactly sure that it would work this way so better ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have video files on your harddrive and you want to serve them all with their filenames, you should just use [Express Static](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) to serve them just like any other resource

You can add a path prefix '/videos' to differentiate them from regular resources.

```
app.use('/videos', express.static('videos'));
```

Then a video file `./videos/myvid.mp4` would be available as http://localhost:8000/videos/myvid.mp4

Answer (score 1):

To have a file available as a file, you need to set the appropriate headers before piping

And to load the file you'd put this code in your router, and where you're using `post`, if you don't have a strong reason I'd just use `get` or `all`

You might also wanna be able to end the transmission if client decides to disconnect mid-stream

Alternatively you might want to go with `res.download` instead of streams, which which case appropriate headers and interruptions are automatically handled.

So the whole code might look like this:

```
router.route('/path/to/video.mp4')
.all(function(req, res){
    res.header('content-disposition', 'filename="video.mp4"')
    var stream = fs.createReadStream('./resources/video.mp4');
    stream.pipe(res);
    require('on-finished')(res, stream.abort.bind(stream));

    // or simply
    res.download(fs.readSync('/path'))
});
```

Then you can use `http://localhost:8000/path/to/video.mp4` to either directly load the video into your browser, it'll play it if it can or simply offer to download. Or you can use this URL  in your `videgular`

```
sources: [ {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:8000/path/to/video.mp4'), type: "video/mp4"} ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Could you tell me how i would load the file from the frontend (taking my example how would you call the stream) ?

Comment: that looks good but how do i make sure that the node server is called? say if the node server runs on port 8105 then it would not be requested when attempting to find source since the default port is 80?

Comment: i know i might be stupid but path to url would that trigger the route('/retrieveFile') say for instance my file path is "user_resources/module/5/video.mp4" ?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Is that the path of where the actual file resides on your machine, or is that the URL path you want for your video file to be served at? If it's the former case, replace that path in your `fs.readStream(path)`, but if it's the latter case, replace it in your router `.router('user_resources/module/5/video.mp4').all(function)` (actually I just realized I made a mistake in that code, see for correction)

Comment: if it is the former wouldnt that mean i would have to create a new route for every file uploaded into my system if i wish to serve it?